# Bootstrap-datepicker - Is it possible to update after each click(year, month, day)?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap-datepicker [link to docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/)
Is it possible to update the input field after each click(year/month/day) instead of waiting util the user has clicked through the whole datepicker?

Any help/tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `changeDate` event to detect when date was changed.

Like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(e){
    // Update the input field
});
```

Comment: Thx. Hi, .on('changeDate') only is triggered when you click through all the steps(year, month, and day). I want the input field to be instantly updated when the user clicks a year, then instantly updated when the user clicks a month and so on.

Comment: See the event object and detect what element was clicked then do what you want.